# Editorial reviews

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, database

For our Magento store we will just use the Review feature for what we call "Editorial/expert reviews". Meaning that we just would like some users to be able to make reviews and others dont.

I was thinking of the approach of insert these comments directly into the database and then disable the option for regular users to make any comment.

As I understand I can disable the entire review feature. But it my case I want it to be there. But I just dont want anyone else to make any product reviews beside the ones already in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways you can tackle this quarterback.

For instance, you can fill a DB with the unique identifier of the users that you want to allow to comment and then on the product page (or wherever) template check to see if the user is one of these people and if so display the comment section, if not, do nothing.

Comment: Will probably do something like this. As I have all the reviews already I'm thinking of just insert them direct into DB and the disable the comment box. But do you know if the review section somhow can be accessed outside the product page. Like the My Account section etc.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/how-to-add-product-reviews-progmatically

Answer (score 1):

easymoden00b is correct. I would do it a little differently though.

I would instead of disabling the review feature (since making a entirely new one would take way too long) I would just make conditional logic that would check to see if the user is allowed to comment. You can do this using `customer attributes`. Set an attribute to yes if they can comment on a review or no if that cant.

So:

1. Create Customer attribute (Allow Review Comments? yes/no)
2. On review page add conditional logic (is person logged in? can person review comments? is attribute set to yes?)
3. Provide access if yes, deny access if no (or hide the comment button o.o)

Note: I would do all this in a custom module. I don't advice editing core code. Or other peoples modules.